# Why is there a FormatException with string using braces ({ })?

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I am trying to create a simple JavaScript file to inject from code behind and want to append variables names to message.

```
 string javascript = string.Format
                            (
                                @"var msg = '{0} ';
                                 if(confirm(msg))
                                {                                          
                                    hdnfield.value='Yes';
                                } else {
                                    hdnfield.value='No';
                                }
                                    submit();", variableName);
```

but getting an FormatException. What is the right way to do this?

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your braces in the if/else statement are not escaped, that is causing problems with the call to `string.Format` which uses braces to indicate the placeholders.

```
string javascript = string.Format
    (
        @"var msg = '{0} ';
         if(confirm(msg))
        {{                                          
            hdnfield.value='Yes';
        }} else {{
            hdnfield.value='No';
        }}
            submit();", variableName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean you're feeding the entire file into a `String.Format(format, value1, value2, value3...)` in ASP.NET.

If so, you're going to have problems doing that with Javascript as it's going to interpret every opening and closing curly brace as a start or end of a token to replace.

You'd probably do better to use some sort of placeholder in the template like `##MYTOKEN##` or `$$SOMEVALUE$$`, load that file into a string and use some `String.Replace(whatToReplace, whattoReplaceItWith)` functions to do the replacements.

Means you can define your own rules on what to replace with what.
`String.Format` is incredibly flexible and powerful, but not with unescaped curly braces in the content.